# Solution does not get online automatically although TFS is connected

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, tfs, projects-and-solutions

Whenever I open Visual Studio, it prompts me my TFS password, which i get successfully logged in too.

1. Now when i open my solution (which is mapped to TFS repository) - it should go online by default but it does not. Also "Go Online" button in Solution Explorer is not visible. When i right click a particular project - I don't see "Get Latest version, Specific Version" etc.

   The only way out is unload any project and the reload it. There after every thing works good.
2. Also, every time i need to build a project manually if i make some changes in any particular file in that project. Although project is selected in configuration manager.

Answer (score 5):

Right Click on the solution in Solution Explorer and select "Go Online". That should help.

Comment: :D ... Nauman, Lemme explain the issue
My solution thinks that it is online (and thus don't show options for 'go online' anywhere). However, files think that they are offline i.e. both are not in sync.

Comment: @RohitKandhal This worked for me.  I think you shouldn't downvote a helpful answer just b/c it doesn't solve things for you.  Your clarification really belongs in your Q and not in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds odd. I'd start by getting a totally clean set of source code.

- Check in any changes you have pending
- Close all open solutions
- Delete your root source folder (Note: I always rename it initially to be sure I don't lose something I later realise I should have saved. So I rename it and only delete it when my new source code image is building ok)
- Open Source Control, right click on the root folder, and 'Get Specific Version'. In the dialog that pops up, tick the two checkboxes so that it forces TFS to get all the source code regardless of what it thinks you already have on your PC.
- Open your solution and rebuild it.

This will give you a clean copy of what is on the server, and it often fixes weird problems that can come about from corrupted information being cached somewhere in your source tree.

If that doesn't fix it, it may be a problem with your VS install or your TFS server setup, but those are just stab-in-the-dark guesses.

For the "not building when you make a change" problem, if it's not fixed by the above, check that the project is set to build in your project configuration, and check that the project dependencies look sensible (you may need to delete and re-add your references if there is a broken project reference in your project)